# Android READ_PHONE_STATE Event

Tags: java, android, loops, broadcast, receiver

Can i use loops in READ_PHONE_STATE event?

I want to work loop when phone started ringing to end ringing.
also same the case of user start calling to disconnect the call.

This is my broadcast receiver class

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        while (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            //wate for user shaking the phone
            //call ansered
        }           
        while (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            //do something while phone answered
            //I want to work something during the calling time
        }
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) {
            //do some
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already done all the necessary research, it's just probably not 'looping' that you want to do.

What you need is to start something when the phone rings, and stops when it stops ringing. Same for in-call.

To handle events while the phone is ringing, start doing something on [CALL_STATE_RINGING](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_RINGING), then wait for either [CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) or [CALL_STATE_IDLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_IDLE) to know when ringing has stopped.

Same for while the user is making a call: start something when your receiver receives [CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) and stop when it receives [CALL_STATE_IDLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_IDLE).

I would have your BroadcastReceiver send a message (or call a function) in your UI thread to do what you need to do, then notify when call state has changed.

You don't need to be looping during those intervals. You just want to start/stop doing something at the right time. You can always put some backup security (eg: if phone rang and nothing happened for 3 mins, I stop doing something) to make sure you won't keep running things when you don't want to be.

Comment: I want to develop a shake to answer application,

While phone ringing, user shake once the phone: call to be answered.
Also user shake 2 time: call become declined

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when an incoming call is picked/dropped, and when an outgoing call is started/stopped so implement your "looping" logic in the associated callbacks. I've included comments in the code below:

```
public abstract class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        static CallStartEndDetector listener;



@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    savedContext = context;
    if(listener == null){
        listener = new CallStartEndDetector();
    }


        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
    telephony.listen(listener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}



public class CallStartEndDetector extends PhoneStateListener {
    int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
    boolean isIncoming;

    public PhonecallStartEndDetector() {}


    //Incoming call-   IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when hung up
    //Outgoing call-  from IDLE to OFFHOOK when dialed out, to IDLE when hunged up

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
        if(lastState == state){
            //No change
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                isIncoming = true;
                 //incoming call started
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing down on them
                if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    isIncoming = false;
                   //outgoing call started
                }
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                //End of call(Idle).  The type depends on the previous state(s)
                if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                    // missed call
                }
                else if(isIncoming){
                      //incoming call ended
                }
                else{
                   //outgoing call ended                                              
                }
                break;
        }
        lastState = state;
    }

}
```

}